# Angular Service making Http requests to localhost:4200 instead of localhost:8080

Tags: angular, spring-boot, http-status-code-404

I have an Angular + Spring Boot project. The Angular project contains services making Http requests to Spring Boot app running on port 8080. When i try to use apiBaseUrl variable from environment in service i get a 404 status as below:

[image]

services is making Http calls to localhost:4200 instead of localhost:8080

environment:

```
export const environment = {
production: false,
apiBaseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080'
};
```

service:

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { environment } from "src/environments/environment";
import { Student } from "./student";

@Injectable ({
providedIn: 'root'
})

export class StudentService {


private apiServerUrl = environment.apiBaseUrl;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

public getStudents(): Observable<Student[]> {

  return this.http.get<Student[]>('${this.apiServerUrl}/student');

}
 //rest of code
```

but when i make a change and give url direct, everything works fine.

```
return this.http.get<Student[]>('http://localhost:8080/student');
```

can someone explain it to me, this is my first angular app, so thank you for your understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using backticks `, not single quotes '

```
  return this.http.get<Student[]>(`${this.apiServerUrl}/student`);
```

Comment: i can't believe i spent so much time to figure it out. You save a lot of my free time. Thanks once again

Comment: Glad to help. If the code does what you're looking for can you mark the answer as answered?

Answer (score 2):

For resolve this problem you Can Change '' by ``  In this line this.http.get<Student[]>('${this.apiServerUrl}/student');

The correct code is :

```
this.http.get<Student[]>(`${this.apiServerUrl}/student`);
```

Or

```
this.http.get<Student[]>(this.apiServerUrl+ '/student');
```

Comment: now i know, it's my first steps with Angular. Thank you !!

Comment: You are welcome,good job